# Should I use glycogen in isopropanol to precipitate RNA or does glycogen have harmful consequences on downstream protocols such as RNA seq?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, rna-sequencing, protocol

I have heard that one can use glycogen in isopropanol to better visualise the RNA pellet after centrifugation. What are the advantages and disadvantages of adding glycogen in isopropanol for RNA quality and quantity?